# Unable to fire a script upon ACPI event occurrence

Tags: bash, headphones, acpi

My intention is to fire a script when my headphones get plugged in into my PC. First of all, in order to check that such event is actually caught, I ran `acpi_listen` and tried to plug/unplug the headphones a few times. Here's the output it gave:

```
jack/headphone HEADPHONE plug
jack/headphone HEADPHONE unplug
jack/headphone HEADPHONE plug
jack/headphone HEADPHONE unplug
```

So, I'm assuming that the event is properly caught. What I then did was to create a new event called `jack-headphone` under `/etc/acpi/events` and fill it with the following content:

```
event=jack/headphone
action=/etc/acpi/jack-headphone.sh %e
```

Finally, I've created the actual script (`/etc/acpi/jack-headphone.sh`) that I'd like to execute whenever I plug/unplug my headphones, then made it executable using

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/acpi/jack-headphone.sh
```

Here's what the actual script looks like:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
set -e -u

if [ "$1" = "jack/headphone" -a "$2" = "HEADPHONE" ]; then
    case "$3" in
        plug)
            pacmd set-source-port 1 analog-input-headset-mic
            ;;
        unplug)
            pacmd set-source-port 1 analog-input-internal-mic
            ;;
    esac
fi
```

The command `pacmd set-source-port 1 analog-input-headset-mic` sets the headphones' microphone as the default input, whereas `pacmd set-source-port 1 analog-input-internal-mic` does the same with the internal microphone. What happens is that if I run such commands in a terminal, they behave as expected, switching the default input to the appropriate one. However, when I plug/unplug my headphones and the script `jack-headphone.sh` gets fired, the default input does not get modified accordingly. How's that possible?

Am I missing something or doing something wrong in here? For the records, I'm using Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Possibly dumb question but should the line: echo "headphones event caught" >> ~/Desktop/acpi_events.txt reference a "hard" location like echo "X" >> /home/user/acpi_events.txt? I would think that it might be best to throw this to a /tmp folder rather than attempting to write back to /home/user folder.

Comment: That indeed did the job, however echoing into a text file was intended to be a simple test, not my ultimate goal. Actually, when I plug my headphones, I'd like to execute `pacmd set-source-port 1 analog-input-headset-mic` to set the headphones' microphone as the default input. What happens is that if I run the command from a terminal, it perfectly works, whereas if I include the very same command inside the `jack-headphone.sh` script, nothing happens when I plug my headphones in. How's that possible?

Comment: Sorry, I'll have to punch out here as it appears that you have done this by the book. I've looked at the scripts in the /etc/acpi directory on my 19.10 box and they all have a similar format.

Comment: Yeah, it appears that the execution of a command results in different behaviors depending on _where_ the command was issued from (a terminal or within a script under `/etc/acpi`). Any idea about why this happens?

Comment: I'm guessing it would be whatever the user context is. You could always echo out the user to see that, might be the issue.

Comment: That's an interesting point. However, it doesn't seem to be the issue. Let me explain better: echoing the user from within the script gives indeed user_id=0 (`id -u`) and user_name=root (`id -u -n`), which are different from what I get if I try to execute the same commands in a standard terminal. So what I did was to execute  `pacmd set-source-port 1 analog-input-headset-mic` while logged in as root, expecting that it wouldn't work, though it actually worked. Did you mean to suggest this approach or were you hinting something different?

Comment: Yes, that's what I had in mind. I think you've checked all the boxes...